# Disable multiple select box onchange with jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, attributes

how i can disable each select box after on change?

**HTML:**

```
<select class="URating" step="1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
<div id="result_1"></div>


<select class="URating" step="2">
  <option value="Lancer">Lancer</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
</select>
<div id="result_2"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".URating").change(function(){
    var steps = $(this).attr("step");
    $.post('rating/module.php', {RatingID:$(this).val(), News:"15", Step:steps},
      function(data){
        $("#result_"+steps).html(data);
        //DISABLE THIS SELECT BOX HERE
      });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Disable what select box, are we supposed to know what your ajax function returns ?

Comment: I think the OP means the one they just selected. We don't need to know what the ajax function returns since the `steps` variable is defined outside the ajax call.

Comment: @mayabelle, that's right

Comment: If it's the one that triggers the event handler, using the step attribute to look it up seems like a bad idea, just select `this` instead, but because of the new scope it needs to be in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".URating").change(function(){
    var steps = $(this).attr("step");
    $.post('rating/module.php', {RatingID:$(this).val(), News:"15", Step:steps},
      function(data){
        $("#result_"+steps).html(data);
        $('select[step=' + steps + ']').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".URating").change(function(){
    var $select = $(this);
    var steps = $select .attr("step");
    $.post('rating/module.php', {RatingID:$(this).val(), News:"15", Step:steps},
      function(data){
        $("#result_"+steps).html(data);

        //DISABLE THIS SELECT BOX HERE
        $select.attr('disabled','disabled');
      });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$select.prop("disabled", true)
```

**[Reference Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tft4t/)**